# Unity3d application development on Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-ec2

I ask here because I've [asked](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1222570/unity3d-mouse-events-not-working-on-amazon-web-ser.html) on the Unity3D forums (in July) and nobody has responded, and I still have the same issue.

I have an AWS EC2 instance and I am using it to develop with Unity3D. 
The problem is that while the keyboard and mouse work perfectly fine in the editor, the mouse stops responding when in "play" mode.

I access my EC2 instance via Windows Remote Desktop, I have an Administrators account and I have all drivers up to date.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I am doing research, so cross-platform compatibility is not a concern. I'm using Windows because the tools I require, require Windows. Changing OS is not an option.

I've tried starting the editor with admin. I've also tried launching the remote desktop with admin. Nothing fixes it.

Even the standard Unity3D demo applications have this issue, so it is not something that I am doing.

Comment: may I ask why do you do that?

Comment: @NikaKasradze I am doing research with Unity and it involves a few applications working together and some heavy calculations at a later date. Therefore, I am using the cloud to do my development and run my experiments.

Comment: Does your code by any chance changes the mouse cursor? If not, and you use W10, try running Unity with Admin privileges. I know, bad idea.

Comment: @MiningSam Nope, no changes to the mouse what-so-ever. I have the same problem with all Unity3D application, even the demo projects. Also, I am using Windows Server 2012 on AWS: There is no option to use Windows 10.

Comment: You can use other operating systems as AMI (one of the key reasons to use EC2 with Unity, next to its G2 instances). Do you start the Editor with Admin privileges?

Comment: @MiningSam I am doing research, so cross-platform compatibility is not a concern. I'm using Windows because the tools I require, require Windows. Changing OS is not an option. Anyway, yeah, I've tried starting the editor with admin. I've also tried launching the remote desktop with admin. Nothing fixes it.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different RDP client (Remote Desktop Client) and/or tweaked its mouse settings? I've not experienced this issue - but I am not using Microsoft's Remote Desktop solution.